# Double cosets in rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is it true that $R/(a,b) \simeq (R/(a))/(b)$? This intuitively makes sense, since modding out by $a$ first and then $b$ should not be any different than modding out by both of them.

Comment: Yes. In both cases the quotient has the effect of setting both $a$ and $b$ equal to zero (and being universal with respect to that property).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the [third isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#Third_isomorphism_theorem_2),

$$R/(a,b)\cong \frac{R/(a)}{(a,b)/(a)}= \frac{R/(a)}{(b)}$$